# Unable to clear out network credentials?

Tags: windows-7, networking, credentials

I live in a university dorm, so to connect the internet I am using the LAN port provided in the room. The first time you connect your laptop it asks you for credentials. After that it never asks you again.

My problem is that I want to change the account I am using. I have literally tried everything i know of like:

1. I have tried clearing all browser data using CCleaner.
2. I have tried clearing the passwords saved in Credentials Manager in Windows.
3. I disabled the Credentials Manager, and, still not working,
4. Tried klist purge.
5. Tried changing lan ports.
6. Tried MAC address spoofing.

When I try to use the `net use` command it tells that there are no entries in the list.

Note that I log off each time I do any of the above and I have tried doing them all together but still same issue. I even tried changing my credentials via the university website and magically after I changed them everything is the same. So what the heck is going on?

Comment: Did you try to connect with another computer? It might be that that first login is used to associate your mac address with your account, or even your lan port.

Comment: One thing for sure that it's not associated with lan port cause i have tried and switched to other ports with no luck, and unfortunately i don't have another pc to try. But lets say that it's mac address is there any solution to that ?

Comment: I searched google and downloaded SMAC which spoof MAC address but same issue. I can't understand how it's eating my credentials after all that.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials are likely stored in the Credential Manager. To view the stored credentials go to, start -> Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> Credential Manager.

You can edit or remove stored credential here.